# The correct excel spreadsheet syntax for a conditional numeric subtraction in a numeric cell

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a very basic question regarding formula syntax in an excel spreadsheet; specifically, I want a numeric cell value to equal the result of another numeric cell value minus "40" if that second cell value is greater than "40". This is to be part of an overall operation to calculate overtime pay for our payroll department.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have excel to verify this, but it should be something like this:

```
=if(A1>40,A1-40,"")

=if(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)

    condition = is cell A1 greater than 40
    if true = subtract 40 from A1
    if false = leave blank.   You could change to "0" as well
```